# Rendering page takes too long because of a big DOM

Tags: angularjs

I'm a newbie in AngularJS.

I have a list of N elements. I create a table (by *ng-repeat* as usual), with a row per element.
In each row, I have a dropbox with all N elements as options (again *ng-repeat* is used).

Since N is big, page rendering takes **too long**.

Is generating dropbox options only when the dropbox is accessed is a solution?
If yes, how it is done.

Update:
The dropbox is a native selection.
N is 200.
The page is loaded in +10 sec.

Comment: Would the solution be to use a dropbox that hits an API to pull its contents on activation?

Comment: @BrendanGreen I don't sure I understand. Do you propose to wrap the dropbox by ng-if? 

I would prefer a solution that dropbox will be presented unconditionally.

Comment: When you make such abstract question, you can not expect concrete answer. What is N ~ 100, 1000, 10000? What is dropbox (native select, your custom component, some libbrary component)? Also if you want working plunk as an answer - give plunk that works slow as question.

Comment: you might have too many **watchers**. Can you remove any two-way data binding? Can you limit the amount of data you need to show with some pagination?

Comment: @PetrAveryanov updated the question